# Mist unable to send transactions?

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, mist, windows

I tried to send a small amount to a second account  using mist however the transaction disappeared from my transaction list, and nothing showed up in my account.  I believe the small amount was still subtracted from my wallet.

subsequently i tried the same transaction using geth, and it worked. the funds even show in my wallets. Whats going on should i abandon mist?

Gracias
Windows 10 64bit Ethereum-Wallet-win64-0-7-5

Answer (score 1):

There is some problem with Mist. Happened same to me quite number of times. Restarting Mist resolves the problem. Even transaction show up in transaction list.Try restarting.